# Code returns a dictionary, how to get this data?

Tags: python, salesforce

When I run this code:

```
sf.Contact.create({'FirstName':'Bob','LastName':'Marley','Email':'bobm@example.com'})
```

It returns a dictionary, as shown in the image below. But how can I get this data? As if I run it not in Jupiter I don't know the result of an operation...

[image]

Comment: Is it Salesforce? Did you check out the [docs](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce#record-management)?

Comment: `result = sf.Contact.create(...)` ? `print(result['id'])`

Comment: @bereal Sure, checked salesforce docs, but it's not something mentioned there, as it's more standard python solution rather than package trick :)

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), you can store it in a variable and get values by keys.

```
>>> output = sf.Contact.create({'FirstName':'Bob','LastName':'Marley','Email':'bobm@example.com'})

>>> output['success']
True

>>> output['id']
'0035E00001029J8QAI'
```

Also, it behaves like regular `dict` so you can call `output.items()`, `output.keys()` and `output.values()` according to your needs.